# Compiling unusual Java class with classpath

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, javac

Hi I'm trying to compile a java file and having a lot of problems accessing all the directories required. For workflow reasons, I'd like to keep all directories as they are.

I need to compile the file:

```
C:\Users\cron\Documents\My Dropbox\Leeds\VAplayer\program\VAreceiver\javatest.java
```

So that it has access to this class directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\java-doc\api\com\cycling74\max
```

And the outputted class file ends up here:

```
C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\Cycling '74\java\classes
```

This is the example provided by Cycling 74 help files:

```
javac -classpath "\Program Files\Common Files\Cycling '74\java\lib\max.jar" MyClass.java
```

I'm not sure what max.jar is? Anyway, when I run `java`c on my machine I get an error saying the command is not recognized so I'm trying to use the full path to `javac.exe`. Here's what I have so far:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javac.exe" -classpath "\Program Files\Common Files\Cycling '74\java\lib\max.jar" "C:\Users\cron\Documents\My Dropbox\Leeds\VAplayer\program\VAreceiver\javatest.java
```

And here's the error I get:

> C:\Users\cron\Documents\My Dropbox\Leeds\VAplayer\program\VAreceiver\javatest.java:1: package com.cycling74.max does not exist
>
> import com.cycling74.max

Obviously it's not seeing the classpath. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Does the jar file you're referring to actually exist?

Comment: No! How on earth did I not check that before now! I'll try locating it and report back. I think I say it in another folder somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies guys! 
I got it sorted. it turns out that max.jar file has been moved to another directory on the latest version of MaxMSP. If anyone else is having trouble with this, the final command is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javac.exe" -classpath "C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\Cycling '74\java\lib\max.jar" -d "C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\Cycling '74\java\classes" "C:\Users\cron\Documents\My Dropbox\Leeds\VAplayer\program\VAreceiver\javatest.java"
```

Thanks again chaps!

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javac.exe" \
-classpath "\Program Files\Common Files\Cycling '74\java\lib\max.jar";"C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\java-doc\api\com\cycling74\max" \
-d "C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\Cycling '74\java\classes" \
"C:\Users\cron\Documents\My Dropbox\Leeds\VAplayer\program\VAreceiver\javatest.java"
```

You need to put the second directory after the jar separated by a `;` (or `:` on UNIX) and use `-d` to specify the output directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the class directory at `C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\java-doc\api\com\cycling74\max`, then you need to add this directory to the class path.

Here's a classpath that includes both `max.jar` and the other directory:

```
-classpath "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Cycling '74\java\lib\max.jar;C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\java-doc\api"
```

If you want to say where the class files should end up, use the switch -d.

Here's the complete compile command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin\javac.exe"  -classpath "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Cycling '74\java\lib\max.jar;C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\java-doc\api"  -d "C:\Program Files\Cycling '74\Max 5.0\Cycling '74\java\classes"  "C:\Users\cron\Documents\My Dropbox\Leeds\VAplayer\program\VAreceiver\javatest.java"
```